# Функция tr не переводит слово, хотя функция translate переводит

Tags: c++, qt, локализация, перевод

Есть такой код:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    const QString dir = "/usr/share/qt6/translations";

    if (translator.load("qt_ru", dir)) {
        QApplication::installTranslator(&translator);
        qDebug() << QApplication::translate("QShortcut", "Open");
        qDebug() << QApplication::tr("Open");
    }

    ...
}
```

Его вывод:

```
"Открыть"
"Open"
```

Почему во втором случае слово "Open" не перевелось?

Comment: Какой язык программирования? Добавьте тег

Comment: @CrazyElf да, вроде, очевидно, что `C++`. Судя по тегу `qt` и внешнему виду кода.

Comment: И тем не менее поиск по тегам не будет работать и люди, подписанные на C++ без метки ваш пост не увидят. Я добавил тег.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QApplication::tr("Open")` эквивалентно `QApplication::translate("QApplication", "Open")`, а в этом контексте перевод для Open не определен.

Используйте `QShortcut::tr("Open")` если хотите использовать перевод используемый для локализации стандартных элементов меню управления.

Либо используйте свой собственный файл интернационализации - тогда можно размещать переводимые фрагменты в любых контекстах, главное внести их в файл перевода в этом же контексте.